# Load API results through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-load

I'm wondering that how API results can load as response comes.

[similar functionality](http://flight.yatra.com/air-search/dom2/trigger?type=O&viewName=normal&flexi=0&noOfSegments=1&origin=BLR&destination=MAA&flight_depart_date=21/04/2014&originCountry=IN&destinationCountry=IN&ADT=1&CHD=0&INF=0&class=Economy)

I think using ajax from database we can get.
But here from API(live results) SOAP API.

any suggestions?

**EDIT**

My current ajax function is

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "<?=base_url()?>search/showresults",
    cache: false,               
    data:datastring,
    beforeSend:function(){
           $('#resultloader').show();
    },
    success: function(response){
        $('#resultloader').hide(500);
        $('#showflightresults').html(response);
    },
    error: function(){                      
         //alert('Error while Sending request..');
    }
});
```

Thank you

Comment: You should loop function which connect to Your data source. Use setTimeout feature in JS. Each async request (for example jquery $.ajax, have in callback function parameter data - which is response from API you use can use on Your website).

Comment: @masahuku i have edited my question check it

Comment: @masahuku Can you please give example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting dataType as `xml` and processData as `false` and check.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "<?=base_url()?>search/showresults",
    cache: false,               
    data:datastring,
    processData: false,
    dataType:"xml",
    beforeSend:function(){
           $('#resultloader').show();
    },
    success: function(response){
        $('#resultloader').hide(500);
        $('#showflightresults').html(response);
    },
    error: function(){                      
         //alert('Error while Sending request..');
    }
});
```

**EDIT:-**

You need to iterate through php array.

```
var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($arrayPHP) ?>;

$.each(arrayFromPHP, function (i, elem) {
    // do your stuff
});
```

Comment: can you please give one example

Comment: Actually what i'm doing is: i'm calling showresults method in search controller, then i'm requesting api results and resopnse is coming in xml format and converting to php array and then loading view. Now what changes i have to do?

Comment: @NareshKamireddy So are you getting the data from the api now?

Comment: Yes i'm able to get data from api in xml format but converting it into php array and then loading view(Codeigniter).

Comment: where i have to iterate? in controller?

Comment: @NareshKamireddy Iterate in the JavaScript and append html depending upon your requirement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50004/discussion-between-naresh-kamireddy-and-wiz-kid)

Answer (score 3):

try use this one

```
formData = {
    param1: param1
}
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "<?=base_url()?>search/showresults",
    cache: false,               
    data: formData,
    dataType: "xml",
    beforeSend:function(){
           $('#resultloader').show();
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('#resultloader').hide(500);
        $('#showflightresults').html(data);
    },
    error: function(){                      
         //alert('Error while Sending request..');
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please give one example

Comment: the concept still same. you can test my app here. https://github.com/datomnurdin/service-finder-mobile

Comment: you can run locally but you need to use ripple chrome extension to allow external web service

Comment: i think it is in java i don't understand

Answer (score 1):

What I do is process and store the results on the server in a background thread that reads from a message queue. In our case, this is for insurance quotes. As each carrier's insurance quote is finished, its premium is stored in our database.

On the client side, we call the server using a timer loop. See [Ben Alman - doTimeout](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/)

You can see this in action at [Autoquoter.com](http://www.autoquoter.com). Just use an illinois zip code and enter some dummy info to get a quote (zipcode=60010 for example). You can view the source for our client side code.

Here is our server side code. Each message is an xml serialized insurance carrier.

```
           var queue = new QueueManagerSoapClient("QueueManagerSoap");
            var messages = queue.RemoveAll(session.Id);
            if (messages.Any())
            {
                var serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Carrier));
                foreach (var message in messages)
                {
                    var carrier = serial.Deserialize(new StringReader(message)) as Carrier;
                    found = carrier != null;
                    if (found)
                    {
                       session.Carriers.Add(carrier);
                    }

                }
                session.SaveChanges();                    
            }
            return View("ResultView",session.Carriers);
```

UPDATED:

There are three components to make this work.

First you'll need to launch an asynchronous request when your web page is loaded. This request would load a page that performs your search. It should store results into your database as they are received, or add them to a message queue service. You'll need to mark the search as completed.

```
<%
    var wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringAync(new Uri("http://baseurl/search/submitrequest"));
%>
```

Secondly, add a timer to your web page that performs an ajax load periodically (every 10 seconds for example)

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
                  $('#resultsDiv').load("/search/showresults");
               },10000);
```

Lastly, you'll need to terminate the interval when all of the results have been stored in the database. You could add something like this at the bottom of the search results page.

```
<% if ( isFinished ) { %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         interval.stop();
    </script>
<% } %>
```

Comment: how i can make it use for me>

Comment: I'm editing my answer to describe this in more detail @user123456789